# How to make dropdown categories in Android?

Tags: android

Currently my layout has 2 Spinners. I want user to select category from first spinner and the second spinner shows the list of items based on the category selected from first spinner. How can I do this ? I have tried googling but couldn't find any useful information. Any sample code ?

Comment: @MD .. acc to stack over flow rules .. show respect to everyone .. so your last line "and never ask such a questions here." can hurt someone's self-respect .. so please take care of such things .. thank you

Comment: @SukhwantSinghGrewal Ya i know. but he find answers on __Google__ also na. without having posted code. we can't help you.

Comment: @MD .. i am totally agree with you but some words can hurt so use words very carefully ..

Comment: @SukhwantSinghGrewal Yup. i get it. Sorry!!! champ it's my fault!!!!!!

Comment: @MD .. thanx for understanding .. +ve and great attitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially allow user to select from first spinner. When user select any category fill second spinner with desired values

You can update your spinner by setting new adapter :

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newStringList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```